# how to fix select2 with jquery ui dialog integration?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

Some time ago I developed a jQuery UI dialog and integrated it with the select2 plugin for a lot of information. At first it worked correctly but then it happens that the dropdown of the select is displayed inside the body and is cut terribly. The dialog is small since it only contains that single element and therefore the size is not enough to display the full combo or at least with a considerable size. Just when I mention the call to select2, the select is displayed with the browser's default style.

If anyone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Greetings.

Here the code of the dialog together with the call to select2:

```
link = $('.change_user_link').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
dialog = $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '.change_user_modal').dialog({
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  title: 'Change Owner',
  buttons: {
    Save: function() { $(this).find('form').submit() },
    Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog('close') }
  },
  open: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove()
  }
});
$('.change_user_select').select2({
    dropdownParent: $(dialog)
})
});
```

Here is the link of the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfBgX.jpg

Comment: Not sure what part of the issue you want fixed. Do you want the dialog to be big enough for the expanded select box or the select box to fit within the content of the dialog box. Please clarify the issue, what you tried, and what the expected result is. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want the dropdown to stand out from the widget. The dropdown is displayed within the foot of the dialog (this is the problem) and before it was displayed above it (this should work). Before this worked for me, I had no problem with this.